# Factory in inner class, not possible?

Tags: java, class, static, java-8, inner-classes

Id like to hide instantiaton details of my inner class from my outer class.
My inner class needs to be non-static in order to access outer's variables

If I try to write a buildNew() static method it throws an error as it seems it is not possible to have static methods in inner classes.

Do I have to rennounce to the feature and instantiate the inner class in parent's or either pass all parent's variables to the inner in order to qualify for static?

Comment: "My inner class needs to be non-static in order to access outer's variables" - not entirely true; you can pass an instance of the outer class to the constructor of a static inner class.

Comment: One of the two rennouncement alternatives I suggest in the last sentence

Comment: Oh, ok - I didn't quite understand what "all parent's variables" might mean, so I didn't realize.

Comment: I appreciate your help and indeed a very good point that could have been useful, just that I am picky :p

Comment: I think “hiding” of whatever and “using inner classes” are contradicting. After all, the outer class may even call `private` constructors of the inner class. If you want to have real encapsulation you shouldn’t use inner classes…

Comment: I did not know that... how is it. It should have perfect sense for me the scenario where a inner class sees outer's variables but you can enforce the opposite is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the two options you outlined (make Inner static or put those factory methods in Outer) are fine and you don't gain much by going with the following, but that's a matter of opinion.

You can replicate the function of static methods and variables by having a singleton (with respect to Outer instance) object to hold them.  In this case, it would look something like this:

```
class Outer {

    int foo = 0;
    int bar = 5;

    private final InnerFactory innerFactory = new InnerFactory();

    List<Inner> test() {
        Inner fromFoo = innerFactory.newFromFoo();
        Inner fromBar = innerFactory.newFromBar();

        return Arrays.asList(fromFoo, fromBar);
    }

    private class InnerFactory {

        Inner newFromFoo() {
            // I'm an inner class, so I can access member variables 
            // of enclosing Outer
            return new Inner(foo);   
        }

        Inner newFromBar() {
            return new Inner(bar);
        }
    }

    public class Inner {

        int baz;

        Inner(int baz) {
            this.baz = baz;
        }
    }

}
```